# Java Selenium UI Test BDD: How to set test result as fail or pass when test is not done yet?

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests, bdd, ui-testing

For example, I have a BDD test:

- Step 1
- Step 2
- Step 3
- Step 4

I want to finish the test as 'PASSED' when there is no element in the html page in 'step 2' ('step 3' and 'step 4' will not work if the element is not displayed). If the element is displayed in the html page, I want it to go to 'step 3'.

How is this done? How can we finish the test as PASSED even if the test is not over?

I tried this for step 2 and it didn't work:

```
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

 jse.executeScript("browserstack_executor: {\"action\": \"setSessionStatus\", \"arguments\":{\"status\": \"passed\", \"reason\": \"passed\"}}");
 driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most BDD tools don't really have a way to interrupt scenarios. There are a few things you could try.

If steps 3 and 4 are *always* meant to pass if the element is missing, check for the element and skip the tests in 3 and 4.

If they will *sometimes* pass even with the element missing, most BDD tools have some kind of context that persists between steps (you can create one in JUnit). By setting a flag or other variable in that context, you could then check it and skip the test in the steps if required.

Bear in mind though that this will cause the tests to appear as if they have passed when actually they weren't even run! So I would be really, really careful in doing this. Consider at the very least logging a warning.

If there are too many steps after step 2 to realistically do this, you could override the test runner and throw a special exception in step 2, then catch it in your test runner to end the test. That will let you handle your exceptional case in an exceptional way (and is therefore probably more maintainable, even if it's harder to set up!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Exception is a good point.